# NSObject to file?

Tags: objective-c

I have a class that is a sub-class of NSObject which contains 3 properties. How can I write this object to a plist file?

Should I create a dictionary, populate it then write the dictionary to file?

or is there a simpler way?

Comment: If you are writing out user preferences, you might also wish to consider NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 5):

You could use a dictionary, but generally, to write objects to a file, you should use NSKeyedArchiver. You will have to implement `-encodeWithCoder:` and `-initWithCoder:`. Then you can just use `[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myObject toFile:path];`. For more information, see the [Archives and Serialization Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i).

However, for your simple 3-property case, a dictionary [could be faster](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/2221-nspropertylistserialization-vs-nskeyedarchiver-performance.html). It's really up to you, I suppose.

Comment: Why is this better than the asker's proposal?

Comment: This is the "right" way to archive objects in Cocoa. Yes, you could use a dictionary, but it will feel a little hackier, really. This way will probably be less of a pain to maintain. I mean, the title of the guide I linked (an official guide) talks about exactly what the OP is trying to do: archive objects.

Comment: I understand, I'm just curious whether there are any particular reasons other than for posterity, such as bindings in interface builder.

Comment: Not bindings, no. NSKeyedArchiver is much more general and can archive full-on objects graphs. But I found a thread that suggests NSPropertyListSerialization / NSDictionary is much faster, so I updated my answer to reflect that as well.